# React Native - Value of type NSString cannot be converted to a ABI44_0_0YGValue

Tags: css, react-native

While working on a react native project I stumbled upon this error:

> **JSON value of "90vh" of type NSString cannot be converted to a ABI44_0_0YGValue. Did you forget the % or pt suffix?**

What does ABI44_0_0YGValue mean? I have tried the pt suffix but the same error still appears. What could be the problem?

I am using styled components to add the width and height value to different elements:

```
import styled from 'styled-components/native';  

const MainWrapper = styled.View`
height: 90vh;
width: ${(Dimensions. get('screen'). width)}px;  
justify-content: center; 
align-items: center; 
background-color: red; 

`

const ScreenTime = ( { navigation } ) => {
  return (
    <MainWrapper>
      <Header>
          <Paragraph>Screen Time</Paragraph>  
      </Header>
    </MainWrapper>
  );
};
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All dimensions in React Native are unitless, and represent density-independent pixels.

In other words, the error is being thrown because React Native is looking for a Number type, not a string.  Unlike CSS for the web, the "vh" and "px" suffixes are meaningless here.

Try:

```
height: 90,
width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
```

Comment: Thanks!
This worked, I just had to remove the quotation marks and the suffix.

Answer (score 0):

Check all related dimensions where this error pops up

In my case was this : width: "100" and simply changed it to width: "100%"

Got fixed , Hope work for you too. :)